# Sylius/Payum/Stripe config error "boolean sandbox option must be set"

Tags: php, stripe-payments, sylius, payum

I have successfully set up the Stripe gateway, however when I try to submit the payment as a user, I get the error, "The boolean sandbox option must be set." I do not get this error with PayPal, only with Stripe.

Here are my relevant config.yml entries:

```
payum:
    gateways:
        paypal_express_checkout:
            factory: "paypal_express_checkout"
            payum.http_client: "@sylius.payum.http_client"
            username: "%paypal.express_checkout.username%"
            password: "%paypal.express_checkout.password%"
            signature: "%paypal.express_checkout.signature%"
            sandbox: true
        stripe:
            factory: stripe_checkout
            publishable_key: pk_test_1UyHCW3tydYjdxYLvaGPRMKh
            secret_key: sk_test_81j9puWh2fTnROgOtIK0hjLb
            sandbox: true

sylius_payment:
     driver: doctrine/orm
     gateways:
        stripe: Stripe
```

What am I doing wrong?

(Also, those are not the real keys)

Answer (score 3):

There was a typo in the PayPal section of the parameters.yml file. I guess it was breaking the config before it could get to the "sandbox: true" line.